# Why can't I use IDL xompile function?

Tags: performance, debugging, installation, idl, issue-tracking

I have installed IDL version 5.2.1 but the codes neither change colors nor the compile function are available.
I can only use the Run function in which after clicking nothing happens still.
What should I do ?
Do I need to reinstall it or is it just a matter of some files/licenses?

I wrote some codes, I couldn't compile and then after clicking on the Run function nothing happend.